# Equivalent to right-click 'inspect element' in iOS simulator Safari?

Tags: css, safari, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, safari-web-inspector

When developing a web app using ionic, it is very useful to run up the program in iOS simulator with the command line

```
ionic run ios -l -c -s --target="iPhone-5s"
```

Then by selecting desktop Safari and Develop -> iOS Simulator you can bring up the Web Inspector for the app on the simulator.
All well and good.

On desktop Safari, it is very useful to right-click on an element to find it in the Web Inspector. Is there a way to do this in iOS Simulator Safari ?

I end up putting a searchable string into the HTML and Ctrl-F to find it which is more cumbersome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a target button in the web inspector window that can select an element inside the iOS Simulator. Here's a screenshot:

["Select Element" button in Web Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZhcG.png)

Comment: Thanks Jacob, had forgotten about that button. Nice!

Comment: As of 2021, the web inspector doesn't show the "select element" icon when inspecting a simulator.  At least on my machine.